# Windows authentication in asp.net 5

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building an intranet application in ASP .NET 5, MVC 6. I want to know how to enable Windows Authentication.? The default project template supports only Individual User Accounts.

Comment: If you plan to host your site on IIS, you can configure windows authentication in IIS

Comment: What about other options like self hosting..?

Comment: Write a middleware I guess

Comment: @user2935752 I know it's been a while, but if you are still looking, see my answer about how to enable this for a self-hosted project.

Answer (score 7):

Mark's answer is still valid in ASP.Net RC1. There are some additional steps to tie it all together (I don't have enough reputation to comment on his solution):

1. Install [WebListener from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener)
2. Add the following usings to Startcup.cs:

   ```cs
   using Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features;
   using Microsoft.Net.Http.Server;
   ```
3. Add [Mark's code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33120878/824036) in the Configure method before app.UseMvc:

   ```cs
   // If we're self-hosting, enable integrated authentication (if we're using
   // IIS, this will be done at the IIS configuration level).
   var listener = app.ServerFeatures.Get<WebListener>();
   if (listener != null)
   {
       listener.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationSchemes = 
       AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
   }
   ```
4. To debug this, you need to [add the WebListener run target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33221097/824036) in `project.json`, as Mark noted in a different answer:

   ```cs
   "commands": {
     "weblistener": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --config hosting.ini",
     "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
   },
   ```
5. Pick weblistener instead of IIS Express of web (Kestrel) to debug your application.

Answer (score 6):

The `$(ProjectDir)\Properties\launchSettings.json` file will trigger Visual Studio to generate a `web.config` file when debugging appropriately for IISExpress that will have the `<authentication/>` node set according to the launch settings.

The below is an example `launchSettings.json`

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:65070/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "commandName": "web",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But also use the extension `app.UseIISPlatformHandler();` instead of manipulating the listener. The extension will set up a middleware that will automatically ask for NTLM and translate the appropriate handles from IIS.

When deploying to IIS, if you're using `WebListener` you have to add the `authentication` node yourself to the `web.config`. If you're using `HttpPlatformHandler` (which I recommend personally) and proxying to kestrel, add `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` to the `httpPlatform` node in the `web.config`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers here, which are for IIS-hosted only, you can enable Windows Authentication in a self-hosted ASP.NET 5 project (tested against beta 7 and beta 8) by adding the following in the Startup.cs `Configure` method, before the `app.UseMvc` or similar that you wish to protect:

**UPDATE FOR BETA 8**

```
// If we're self-hosting, enable integrated authentication (if we're using
// IIS, this will be done at the IIS configuration level).
var listener = app.ServerFeatures.Get<WebListener>();
if (listener != null)
{
    listener.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationSchemes = 
        AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
}
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER FOR BETA 7**

```
// If we're self-hosting, enable windows/integrated authentication.
// For IIS, this needs to be configured in IIS instead, and the
// following will have no effect.
if ((app.Server as ServerInformation) != null)
{
  var serverInformation = (ServerInformation)app.Server;
  serverInformation.Listener.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationSchemes = 
      AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
}
```

Adapted from the official [MusicStore example](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/StartupNtlmAuthentication.cs#L98).

If you're debugging using Visual Studio 2015 with IIS Express, you can turn on Windows Authentication via a checkbox in the debug properties page for a project now, rather than messing with the `applicationhost.config` file. I couldn't get the web.config solution to work for IIS Express debugging, it throws an error about the configuration not being valid at that level. **Note this does not currently work in beta 8 - see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/419)**

Answer (score 4):

With IIS hosting, you can add a web.config file to your wwwroot directory with IIS configurations for your application.

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did everything that i found on internet, no one worked. So, i looked to the aspnet 4.5 configuration files, and i saw that it uses:

```
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>enabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
```

on .csproj file, i just copied to .xproj file of aspnet 5 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are building a new application you can change the authentication type by clicking `Change Authentication`.  This will bring up a selection where you can change type type to Windows Authentication.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For RC1 & IISExpress from an empty Web Application:

- Right click web project, select `Properties`
- Click `Debug` tab, check `Enable Windows Authentication`

This affected `~/Properties/launchSettings.json` as follows:

```
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": false,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure manually IIS Express (in VS2015 CTP6).
For do that, edit applicationhost.config file.
(C:\Users\your username\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config)

In configuration tag add this :

```
<location path="{your site name}">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```