# Adding authorization to Asp.net 5 Vnext Config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to limit user access in my Asp.net 5 Vnext solution.

in class way i used this line in root **web.config** :

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="domain\user" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

but thats not working in new MVC 6 project. modified **wwwroot\web.config** :

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>

  </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="domain\user" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

I even tried this and still all windows user can access it :

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Deny" users="unknownname" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="knownname" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

cant find right approach for user limitation in asp.net vnext.

Update:
new error appears after following link suggestion :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the last option with authentication instead of authorization? so: <security><authentication>xxx</authentication></security>

Comment: @janpieter_z thanks for respond but it gave me 500 server error if i replace those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows authentication in asp.net 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542141/windows-authentication-in-asp-net-5). Note that the `system.webServer` section only applies to IIS/IIS Express, so if you are hosting the app another way these settings won't work.