# User.IsInRole is always false when using IIS Express / Kestrel in ASP.Net 5 with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net 5 application using version 1.0.0-rc1-update1 with Windows Authentication. I've implemented a custom policy in my Startup.cs file:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other configuration code

    var viewCharts = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddRequirements(new ViewChartsRequirement())
        .Build();

    collection.AddAuthorization(opts =>
    {
        opts.AddPolicy(Policy.ViewCharts, viewCharts);
    });

    collection.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, ViewChartsHandler>();

    // ... other configuration code
}
```

The `ViewChartsHandler`'s `Handle` method is as follows:

```cs
protected override void Handle(
    AuthorizationContext context,
    T requirement)
{
    var identities = _securityRepo.GetIdentitiesForPolicy(_policy);

    // this returns a result when using a web listener, but
    // never finds a match when using IIS Express
    var matchingIdentity = identities.FirstOrDefault(role => context.User.IsInRole(role));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(matchingIdentity))
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
}
```

**When using a web listener as [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542141/windows-authentication-in-asp-net-5/34279064#34279064), the code above works.** However, when using IIS Express it never finds a `matchingIdentity`.

Things to note:

1. My IIS Express is configured to use Windows Authentication, and deny Anonymous Authentication. The bug related to IIS Express and this [was fixed in RC1](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/332).
2. The username from Windows is always resolving correctly.
3. In the `Handle` code above, `context.User` is an instance of `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal` when using a web listener, but when using IIS Express it is a `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal`.
4. I have `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` set in my web.config.

I think this is a role provider problem, but I am at a loss as to how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `User.IsInRole` does not function correctly in RC1. (See @blowdart's comments.) This will be fixed in RC2.

The original code will work **so long as the line below returns the SIDs for each AD group**, as opposed to the friendly names.

```cs
// This line must return SIDs instead of friendly names
var identities = _securityRepo.GetIdentitiesForPolicy(_policy);
```

#### Update

This was fixed in RC2. The original code works!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following code to successfully check for role membership on RC1, **however** note that it does not resolve group names (probably due to the problems referred to by @blowdart), I have to supply the group names as SIDs:

```
// Set up authorisation policies from the configured AD group lists.
// NOTE: Currently this only works with SIDs if hosting using Kestrel 
// behind IIS, not friendly group names.
var viewerGroups = Configuration.GetSection("Groups:Viewer").Value.Split(',');
var adminGroups = Configuration.GetSection("Groups:Admin").Value.Split(',');
services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
{
    auth.AddPolicy("viewer", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireRole(viewerGroups);
    });
    auth.AddPolicy("admin", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireRole(adminGroups);
    });
});
```

I don't know if this will help you, but I thought I'd offer it up in case!

Comment: Thanks, Mark! Your mention of SID's lead me to an answer that will work while we await RC2.

Comment: Glad it was some help @Will

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the IISPlatformHandler middleware?

```
app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
```

This needs to be ran before app.UseMvc(), app.UseStaticFiles() or any other authentication middleware.

Comment: Yup! I am using app.UseIISPlatformHandler and invoking it before any UseStatic and UseMvc calls. However, since the authentication handlers are added in the ConfigureServices method, they are invoked before app.UserIISPlatformHandler as ConfigureServices is called before Configure.

Comment: Oh wait. IsInRole? That's, err, broken in RC1. It is fixed in RC2.

Comment: Whoa! Do you have an supporting sources for me look into on that? I can't find anything in the RC2 announcements: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+milestone%3A1.0.0-rc2

Comment: Well I'm the asp.net security person, so I'm the source  I can try to find the github issue if you like but I'm off to a conference until Friday.

Comment: Ahh, well that's certainly enough for me! I'll be eagerly awaiting the fix in RC2 then!

Comment: Cool, because I'll be damned if I can find the issue now :)